# Find minimum value of parameter

Tags: differential-equations, mathematical-optimization

I have solve the following nonlinear ODE,

```
   (*u'(t)=u^2(t)+1, 0<t<=1*)
```

and got the following approximate solution:

```
  u2 = h - (-1 - h^2) t + h t^2 + h^3 t^2 + t^3/3 + (2 h^2 t^3)/3 + (
       h^4 t^3)/3
```

Then I calculate the residual error to check the accuracy by:

```
     Subscript[r, 2][t_, h_] = \!\(
      \*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]u2\) - u2^2 - 1
```

and I got:

```
      h^2 + 2 h t + 2 h^3 t + t^2 + 2 h^2 t^2 + 
      h^4 t^2 - (h - (-1 - h^2) t + h t^2 + h^3 t^2 + t^3/3 + (2 h^2 t^3)/
       3 + (h^4 t^3)/3)^2
```

I need to get the value of h which make the residual minimum,

Thanks

Comment: Your `u2` looks like the result of `AsymptoticDSolveValue[{u'[t] == u[t]^2 + 1, u[0] == h}, 
 u[t], {t, 0, 3}]`, you probably can go this direction. As to find minimum, just use `Minimize[<your expression with h>]`.

Comment: Dear Alx, I do not have such function in my version 11, could please help me with minimize

Comment: I used `Minimize[h^2 + 2 h t + 2 h^3 t + t^2 + 2 h^2 t^2 + h^4 t^2 - (h - (-1 - h^2) t + h t^2 + h^3 t^2 + t^3/3 + (2 h^2 t^3)/3 + (h^4 t^3)/3)^2, h]` with your expression in question, the answer is `h = 0` if `t = 0`.

Comment: Thank you Alx, I solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not solve diffequation directly?

```
u[c1_] = u /. First@DSolve[u'[t] == u[t]^2 + 1, u, t] /. C[1] -> c1

(*   Function[{t}, Tan[t + c1]]   *)

Plot[Evaluate@Table[u[c1][t], {c1, -3, 3}], {t, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: Dear, I am using my method, so I need to find minimum value of h, which I hope to be 0...

Comment: Can you use your suggested way for system of ODE?can you give me an example of system